# IBM Worklight 5.0.5.2 - How to change the Android package name

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

In worklight it seems that the android package name is set by the varible `${packageName}`.

Where is this variable set? And how can I change it?

Right now the default seems to be `com.applicationName`.
 In the app im working on, this package name already exists in Google Play, so I would like to change it to `com.corperationName.applicationName`.

I know I can do this via Ant during Android project compilation, but I was wondering if there was somewhere within Worklight I can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this for Shell and Inner projects by making the following changes to the Shell project (check in or backup the shell and test before committing changes):

- Add the following dir structure to the ShellApp/android/native/src
  directory: com/corpname/{$appName}
- Copy the contents of the ${packageDirectory} directory into the new
  {$appName} directory (for me it was
  ${appName}.java.wltemplate.wluser, ForegroundService.java.wltemplate,
  GCMIntentService.java.wltemplate).
- In the files copied, every reference to ${packageName} needs to be
  replaced with com.corpname.{$appName}
- In AndroidManifest.xml.wltemplate.wluser, every reference to
  ${packageName} needs to be replaced with com.corpname.{$appName}.
- Remove the ${packageDirectory} from the project.

Every inner project created from this Shell project should now have the package structure as com.corpname.appname